# Does anyone know details about PERM-AR-DO?

Tags: android, specifications, access-control, sim-card, globalplatform

According to https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc.html,

> AR-DO (E3) is extended to include PERM-AR-DO (DB), which is an 8-byte bit mask representing 64 separate permissions.

Does anyone know the specification for PERM-AR-DO?

GlobalPlatform Secure Element Access Control specifications version 1.0 and 1.1 do not contain it. For the access rule data object, AR-DO (0xE3), only tags 0xD0 and 0xD1 are defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data object PERM-AR-DO (tag 0xDB), just as the other data objects defined on the [UICC Carrier Privileges page](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc.html) (DeviceAppID-REF-DO with SHA-256 and PKG-REF-DO), is a Google-specific extension to the GP Secure Element Access Control specification. Consequently, you won't find anything about these DOs in the GP specifications.

The page that you linked actually provides an answer to your question in the FAQ section:

> **We assume we can grant access to all carrier-based permissions or have a finer-grained control. What will define the mapping between the bit mask and the actual permissions then? One permission per class? One permission per method specifically? Will 64 separate permissions be enough in the long run?**
>
> *A: This is reserved for the future, and we welcome suggestions.*

So the answer is that the interpretation of the PERM-AR-DO is not yet defined. This is also reflected in the Android source code that parses the access rules (in [UiccCarrierPrivilegeRules.java on lines 591-601](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/android-7.0.0_r14/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/UiccCarrierPrivilegeRules.java#591)):

```
    } else if (rule.startsWith(TAG_AR_DO)) {
        TLV arDo = new TLV(TAG_AR_DO); //E3
        rule = arDo.parse(rule, false);
        // Skip unrelated rules.
        if (!arDo.value.startsWith(TAG_PERM_AR_DO)) {
            return null;
        }
        TLV permDo = new TLV(TAG_PERM_AR_DO); //DB
        permDo.parse(arDo.value, true);
    } else  {
```

This code parses the AR-DO and extracts the PERM-AR-DO but then simply drops the extracted value (`permDo`).

Similarly, the resulting `AccessRule` object contains a value `accessType` which is always set to 0:

```
    long accessType = 0;
    [...]
    AccessRule accessRule = new AccessRule(IccUtils.hexStringToBytes(certificateHash),
                                           packageName, accessType);
```

Moreover, inside the class `AccessRule` there is a comment besides the field `accessType` that indicates that the field is "*not currently used*":

```
    public long accessType;   // This bit is not currently used, but reserved for future use.
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer.
I have not mentioned DeviceAppID-REF-DO with SHA-256 and PKG-REF-DO as they seem to be optional and I used DeviceAppID-REF-DO with SHA-1 (also it is not recommended) and leave out PKG-REF-DO.

Comment: One open question: The PERM-AR-DO tag seem to be mandatory to be granted carrier privileges if I interpret the Android source code correctly. So without this tag in a Access Rule, no Carrier privileges can be achieved. Is that correct? And if so is there an equivalent to be recognized as suchin Access Rule Files (ARF) PKCS#15 file based

Comment: @AndyNullcouch The current implementation in Android seems to grant access regardless of the existence of the PERM-AR-DO. Regarding the PKCS#15 ARF: If I interprented the implementation correctly, then there is currently no equivalent for the ARF. The `accessType` field is simply set to 0 for all certificate entries.

Comment: I created this rule in ARA-M: E2 22  (REF-AR-DO)
                               E1 18 (REF-DO)
                                               4F 00
                                               C1 14 ABCD92CBB156B280FA4E1429A6ECEEB6E5C1BFE4
                               E3 06 D0 01 01 D10101  but the test app (CtsCarrierApiTestCases.apk) is showing the exception junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: This test requires a SIM card with carrier privilege rule on it.
Cert hash: 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81

Comment: Any idea why? My only idea was that this missing DB tag is required.

Comment: @AndyNullcouch I'm not sure I understand your problem. If 61ed377e85d386a8dfee6b864bd85b0bfaa5af81 is your SHA-1 certificate hash (i.e. one of the hashes obtained through `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1).digest(signature.toByteArray())` over one of the signatures in `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures`), why would you expect that rule (with a different hash) to match your package?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I pasted the wrong SHA-1 in my command here in the comment. Of course it should have been the matching SHA1 to the exception.( C1 14 61ED377E85D386A8DFEE6B864BD85B0BFAA5AF81). I can even see on a SIM-ME trace that the phone (tried with two different Android N phones) retrieves this rule, but still I am getting this exception.

Comment: @AndyNullcouch Hmm, then I have no idea why it would not work.

Comment: I have now a SIM card supporting all the tags, but on the devices tested before it still fails. Nevertheless I received a different device, and there it is working.

Comment: @AndyNullcouch Would you mind sharing what devices + Android versions you tested?

Comment: All tests were done on Android N (7.0) devices across available vendors in connection with the matching version of CTS. It figured out that the mechanism seems only to be working if a certain debug level is activated. In contact with device vendors to get clarification.

Comment: Late, but nevertheless some maybe useful information: The reason why it did not work for some devices, is that the ARA-M applet was not installed multi-selectable due to CarrierPrivileges tries to select the applet before SmartcardService has finished. (That did not happen in debug HIGH mode due to more logging and different timing)
Also I got an explanation that for ARF not working with my SIMs as Google uses hard-coded values for AC Main instead of using Files IDs in the mentioned in the ARF.

Answer (score 0):

Table 6-8 of the Global Platform Device API Access Control specification (https://globalplatform.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/GPD_Device_API_Access_Control_v1.0_PublicRelease.pdf) defines PERM-AR-DO.  But that really just contains three bits that mean "default" and all othe bits RFU.